# Настройка шрифтов в редакторе Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Поставил себе Unity и такое впечатление, что в редакторе что-то не то со шрифтами...
Какие-то они мелкие что ли... Нельзя где-то в настройках это поменять? 
Искал и не нашел...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сам шрифт можно поменять, размер нельзя. По крайней мере нельзя "легальным" способом, начиная с версии, где используются UIElements, можно рипнуть и поменять все, начиная от шрифта и заканчивая конкретным отступами.

Comment: В какой-то момент (не отслеживал специально, но в 2019.3.7 оно есть) появилась возможность изменять масштаб элементов интерфейса, но параметр влияет и на размер значков. Попробуйте, может, вам подойдёт. `Edit -> Preferences -> UI Scaling`